# Could not find artifact org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:jar:1.1.3 in grailsCentral (http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins)

Tags: grails

I've added:

```
dependencies {

    compile 'org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:1.1.3'


   ....
}
```

And the dependency is right at http://repo.grails.org/grails/plugins/org/grails/plugins/audit-logging/1.1.3/

`compile 'org.grails.plugins:audit-logging:2.0.6'` works though.
What is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting the dependency on `plugins` instead of `dependencies` block worked. This is not mentioned on the documentation.